# LabVIEW initializing and closing VISA resources, dynamically, in event structures

Tags: loops, labview

I'm wanting to initiate different resources live through the user front end. There are multiple purposes this, such as

- Being able to engage various resources, if you have them on hand at the time. This will then consequentially allow various programs to be run, based on what is engaged.
- A program can run and then sit in an idle measurement state to track behavior afterward.
- A user doesn't have to re-initialize connections to working pieces of equipment to start a new program and knows the current state if remote.

I was thinking it'd look something like this:

[image: LabVIEW Front Panel Example]

The problem I'm having is figuring out what structures to be able to use. What I currently use is probably not ideal, and I'm having a few issues with my implementation. I'll walk you through what I was thinking

1. Use an encompassing **while loop** to keep the program running, change resources and run subprograms on resources.
2. Use **event structures** with a timeout inside (1) for the initialization buttons would be ideal, to process the initialization or closure of VISA resources.
3. Using an **enum shift register** to make a state machine in the encompassing while loop (1), to have different states for the UI as it runs subprograms or as different combinations of resources are turned on/off.

It'll look something like this:

[image: LabVIEW Code Structure]

I'm confused about a few things though:

1. a) **Can I initialize VISA resources through event structures within the larger program while loop?**

   b) It seems that it's pretty easy to wire all the resource names to tunnel through to some after program logic, but the error propagation tunnels will have the hollow dots due to each button case initializing only one resource. **Is this problematic further down the line?**

   c) Also, closure and initialization in the same case structure would look trippy as... **should I split these into two case structures, which only respond to their corresponding true/false state?**
2. To run a program later, I was going to use another event structure to respond to a button click. Before executing I would check resources are enabled and that the program is valid to run. Running a program would change the machine state, ie. running subprogram, running subprogram continuously, idle, etc, based on user selection.

   I figured the blocks for this would look like a case structure inside the button event structure. There would be a case for each program, giving an error message if the setup if not appropriate.

   a) **Is there an issue having multiple event structures?** Timeouts would ensure each event structure would run, but I can't do that as the program event structure might need to run for a long time during a program. It would also be nice to have UI updates based on user interaction with the interface.

Thanks in advance for your help & advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rework your application a bit, now it is done with wrong approach. Your while loop will be blocked, b/c on each iteration it will require that each of event structures will catch an event - but you don't want to init/deinit device on each loop iteration.

Your while loop should contain only one Event Structure. Keep all the data passing around it (and case structure) in the cluster, in the shift register. Connect that wire with cluster through all cases/pages of Event Structure, and Case Selector.

Your state machine could be implemented as the following: while loop, inside is case structure with enum selector (for state machine states). One of the state will be "Wait for event", where will be placed single Event Structure. Your state machine should go to "Wait for event" state each time, when it waits for further commands.

As an example, check "[JKI State Machine](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/cs/nid/209025)" - it is great starting point for developing of applications with such an architecture.
To have more flexibility, you could implement Producer-Consumer Queued State Machine.
Overall, list of common patterns you could find by this link - https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_Overview.

Comment: I haven't used clusters very much, but smart way of packing up variables and unpacking to pass through each loop iteration! Good description of the structure. Thanks!
Any reason why I couldn't just add short timeouts to my event structures to stop the block? I misunderstood the condition of a timeout, and thought it would interrupt executing code. It seems to me all event structures could have short timeouts to iterate through?
I'm going to checkout those resources you specified too.

Comment: Yes, timeout will interrupt it - but you don't have it on the screen (default value, if not connected, is - 1,thus there will be no timeout). But if you could implement everything in single event structure, there is no need to have 3. It is not proper design pattern. Design patterns - are something what is tested and proved to be working, so it is always a good practice to follow them...